# Password Validation in Visual Studio 2012 - using BindingSource and SQL database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, passwords

I need help. Need to do password validation and have no idea why it doesn't work. Could someone tell me what my code is missing or what is actually wrong with my way of thinking? I am connecting it to dataset2 where is the table called Users2. Table consists of two columns: 'Username' and 'Password'. Users2BiningSource.Find should be returning value of an index where a current query is. The returned value is always -1, what I guess means that is not found (false). I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 along with SQL server 2008 SP3, all on windows 7. Thank you for your time and help!

```
Imports Hotel_Booking_System.DataSet2TableAdapters



Public Class Logging


Public Sub check_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Check_Details()
End Sub


Private Sub Quit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Public Sub Logging_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Users2TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet2.Users2)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSet2.Users2' table. You can move,     or remove it, as needed.

End Sub

Public Sub Check_Details()

Me.Users2BindingSource.AddNew()

    Dim Usrnm As String = ""
    Usrnm = txtUsername.Text
    Dim Pswrd As String = ""
    Pswrd = txtPassword.Text
    Dim Found As Integer
    Found = Users2BindingSource.Find("Username", Usrnm)
    Dim Found2 As Integer
    Found2 = Users2BindingSource.Find("Password", Pswrd)


    If Found >= 0 And Found2 >= 0 And Usrnm = "Admin" Then
        Me.Hide()
        Booking.Show()
    ElseIf Found >= 0 And Found2 >= 0 Then
        Me.Hide()
        Rooms.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Wrong username or password. Please try again", MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton1,     "SOMETHING WENT WRONG")
    End If
    Label1.Text = Found 'checking the value of found
    Label2.Text = Found2 ' checking the value of found2
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Hopefully you should be hashing the password before performing a comparison!

Comment: I guess this is not a problem.